# Production servers and SSH

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssh

I'm new in this topic and I'm asking myself how I have to configure my production server in relation to SSH. What is the best way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"It depends"

Is it a publicly accessible server? If so, you may want to run it on a non-standard port (popular security-by-obscurity tactic that keeps away ssh probers), disallow password authentication (might be a good idea anyway), disallow root authentication (see previous point), restrict access with iptables or set up fail2ban and iptables rules that limit connections/minute.

If not, you may want to relax some of these constraints.

A few tips that always apply:

- Disable ssh version 1
- Some of Ubuntu's defaults are great, don't mess with them. I mean these:

  - UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
  - StrictModes yes
  - RSAAuthentication yes
  - PubkeyAuthentication yes
  - IgnoreRhosts yes
  - RhostsRSAAuthentication no
  - HostbasedAuthentication no
  - PermitEmptyPasswords no
  - TCPKeepAlive yes
  - AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
- If you authenticate against ldap, use ldap to store public keys too
- Keep an eye on /var/log/auth.log for failed logins